# SHA-1, RFC3174 and RFC4634

Tags: c, sha1

New to the community, but not new to programming.

I've been trying to get a collection of hash functions up/running and I succeeded. However I found some weird results and haven't been able to put my finger on it yet. RFC4634 contains a C implementation for SHA-1 and SHA-2 family, which also can accept a file being passed on for hashing. RFC3174 contains a C implementation, but doesn't process file streams. I've been using the C implementation from RFC4634 to verify files, yet the verification process is returning non similar results when I compare them against SHA-1 provided hashes.

Any idea what the reasons could be?

Comment: As an aside, you can find good C implementations of crypto algorithms on [Brian Gladman's page](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/cryptography_technology/sha/index.php) in case you have more luck with them! They're usually easier to integrate than e.g. OpenSSL's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check if you opened the files in ASCII or binary mode? Line end translation may be performed before the hash is being calculated.

**Update:**

I just compiled the RFC4634 `shatest`and tried on a sample text file. As long as there isn't a line break, all tools agree. Once you insert a line break, results depend: if the text file uses CR and LF (DOS mode), then shatest produces a different result. If the line end is only LF (UNIX), it still agrees with the other tools.

**Update 2:**

In the file `shatest.c` of RFC4634, in function `hashfile(...)`, set `fopen` to binary mode:

```
FILE *hashfp = (strcmp(hashfilename, "-") == 0) ? stdin :
        fopen(hashfilename, "rb");
/*                            ^ HERE */
```

Comment: Is their a difference between the SHA-1 implementation of RFC3174 and RFC4634?

Comment: Not according to RFC 4634: "The code provided herein supports input strings of arbitrary bit length.  SHA-1's sample code from [RFC3174] has also been updated to  handle input strings of arbitrary bit length."

Comment: The implementation provided with RFC3174 lacked the ability to hash a file. So I used to the C implementation provided within RFC4634 and the hash outputs didn't match the given hashes. The code supports hashing with and without spaces.

Comment: Can you post the client code using the RFC4634 implementation?

Comment: I understand the initial part, the one describing the "abc" as the message and padding it with a 1 and 423 0's and adding a block (64bit) with the length of the message. However I'm confused if I have a longer message I want to hash and how I'm supposed to interpret it.

Comment: Apparently adding a binary flag with a read flags returns a correct hash. Thanks for your input.

Comment: To answer your question about padding: the padded message always needs to be a multiple of 512 bits long: 24 ("abc") + 1 (1) + 423 (0...) + 64 (length) = 512. If you have a longer message, you pad to the **next multiple** of 512 bits. So if you have a file with eg. 1234 bytes (9'872 bits), you'll add a one bit, 303 zero bits, and the original length (9872) as a 64-bit number.